# Separate AndroidManifest in two files because its big

Tags: android, gradle

in our project we use a lot of intent-filters for deeplinks.
This creates a big AndroidManifest.xml file. Because we want to expand the using of deeplinks i'm searching for a possibility to separate the AndroidManifest into 2 files or more.

I want a Manifest-file for intent-filters and one for the rest.
Is there a good solution to realize it or should i have to struggle with one AndroidManifest.xml?

I read about the selector examples in the manifest-merger but it looks like its only for permissions (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger)

Thank you.

Comment: Manifest merger is really used for Android library projects merging with the application project. You can break your app in separate libraries but I highly doubt your application is really that big. Do you mind posting it? You should always try to use `Fragments` over `Activities` where possible.

Comment: We are using 1 main-activity and working with a lot of fragments.
The only thing i want is to separate the "deeplink"-registration (intent-filter) from the AndroidManifest.

We have 200 lines of code only for the intent-filter atm. And they will be a lot more in the next weeks...

Answer (score 1):

With Android Studio you can create a module to handle the deep link. It will merge the manifest of all your modules in a single one. So to me, that's a good solution to keep the main manifest clean. Of course, with that piece of manifest, you will have to move the logic (activities, broadcasts, and so on) that you use related to that piece of manifest.